# getops if than else

Tags: bash, grep

I have working getops function

```
m) MONTH=$OPTARG
                  for file in *eqllogmgr* ;
                  do ftx $file |
                  layoutcc ;
            cat $file | grep '\-'$MONTH |
            perl -ne 'print if /-2018/' |
            perl -pe 's/......-2018/\e[1;32m$&\e[0m/g' |
                    sed '$d' ;
                    echo ;
                    ft1 ;
                    done ;;
```

I am trying to alter the grep to evaluate the $MONTH and use the grep i need depending on what the user inputs for the MONTH.

I tried this

```
t) MONTH=$OPTARG

 if [[ $MONTH =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
    for file in *eqllogmgr* ;
    do ftx $file | 
    layoutcc ;
               cat $file | grep $MONTH |
               perl -ne 'print if /-2018/' |
               perl -pe 's/......-2018/\e[1;32m$&\e[0m/g' |
                             sed '$d' ;
                             echo ;
                             ft1 ;
                             fi ;
                             done ;;

  else
    for file in *eqllogmgr* ;
    do ftx $file | 
    layoutcc ;
                cat $file | grep '\-'$MONTH |
                perl -ne 'print if /-2018/' |
                perl -pe 's/......-2018/\e[1;32m$&\e[0m/g' |
                               sed '$d' ;
                               echo ;
                               ft1 ;
                               fi ;
                               done ;;
```

But i get errors for the fi 
i have tried moving that fi around and i cant seem to figure out what i am missing.

Basicly i want to look for a number in the variable and if it has one 
run the grep on the base variable $MONTH

If it has no number i want to grep the variable with a dash in front of it
'-'$MONTH

I tired this as well and i get the same 
syntax error near unexpected token `else'
so i am pretty sure its just the way i am using the if else statement

```
u) MONTH=$OPTARG
for file in *eqllogmgr* ;
                     do ftx $file |
                             layoutcc ;
                     cat $file | 
                    if [[ $MONTH =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
                    grep $MONTH |
                    else
                    grep '\-'$MONTH |
                    fi
        perl -ne 'print if /-2018/' |
        perl -pe 's/......-2018/\e[1;32m$&\e[0m/g' |
                sed '$d' ;
                     echo ;
                     ft1 ;
                     done ;;
```

Adding my final working version for reference ===========================

```
m) MONTH=$OPTARG

        if [[ "$MONTH" = [0-9]* ]]; then
            grep_expr=$MONTH
        else
            grep_expr='\-'$MONTH
        fi

   for file in *eqllogmgr* ; do
     ftx "$file" | layoutcc
     grep "$grep_expr" "$file" | perl -ne 'print if /-2018/' | perl -pe 's/......-2018/\e[1;32m$&\e[0m/g' | sed '$d'
     echo
     ft1
   done 

   ;;
```

Comment: Help us help you. What errors do you get? Do you have sample input and expected output? Can you describe what you're trying to achieve more precisely? I'm almost certain that a pipe with five commands within a for loop in an if/else statement within a case statement in a getopts loop isn't the most simple way to tackle your problem.

Comment: This is used to look for dates in a huge log file

Comment: 1058028:18946:SataSumo1:SP:24-Aug-2018 09:08:22.112896:scsi_miniport.c:827:INFO::28.2.98:Enclosure channel card 0 is operating properly.

Comment: -bash: /support/users/getitdone/.Funktions: line 1251: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
-bash: /support/users/getitdone/.Funktions: line 1251: `fi ;'
-bash: /support/users/getitdone/.Funktions: line 1251: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
-bash: /support/users/getitdone/.Funktions: line 1251: `fi ;'

Comment: So if i have 5 log files it will look at the log files and print out the name of the file and then search the file for all the events for what month i enter... I had to add a "-" in front of the month to prevent it from finding random non month entries where dec was in a word .... But i would like to be able to put in an exact date and month so i need the grep to change if it sees numbers

Comment: I guess it would be simpler if i could just put the if else for just the grep line and then continue with the rest of the script

Comment: The `fi`s don't match up with the corresponding `if`s. You have an `if`/`else`, with a `for` loop in each clause, but the `fi`s are placed before the `done` of each loop. Also, there should only be one `fi`. You don't need a `fi` to terminate the `if` clause because the `else` already does that. You just need to terminate the `else` clause.

Comment: You also have one too many `;;`s. Get rid of the first one.

Comment: Not sure if i should start a new question on this but, this works now as expected but.  If i use two numbers it does not work....   log -u oct    WORKS  .......  log -u 2-oct   WORKS...........      log -u 23-oct    Does not work, as it does not find the events from 23rd of october in my file

Comment: :23-Aug-2018   , this is a 2 digit date int he log file

Comment: : 3-Aug-2018 , single digit date in the log file

Comment: Is it because there is no space between the : on the double digit dates ?

Comment: It is working now not sure what was going on earlier, but it seems to be working as i expected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What (I think) you're trying to do:

```
case-value)
  if ... ; then
    for ...; do
    done
  else
    for ...; do
    done
  fi
  ;;
```

What you have shown in your question:

```
case-value)
  if ...; then
    for ...; do
      fi
    done
    ;;
  else
    for ...; do
      fi
    done
    ;;
```

The first `fi` and the first `;;` are both extraneous. The second `fi` is misplaced inside the second `for` loop.

In the edit you made to your question, you seem to have changed tack and are now trying to accomplish your goal with a single `for` loop containing an `if/else`, as opposed to an `if/else` with a `for` loop in each clause. That's definitely more efficient, <s>but you can't use an `if/else` the way you're trying to. At least, not without a lot of unnecessary messiness</s> (actually you can, but you have to get rid of a couple extra `|`s -- see below). Since your `grep` expression only varies by a couple characters, you can just store the expression in a variable, and use your `if/else` to set the expression:

```
u) MONTH=$OPTARG

   if [[ "$MONTH" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
     grep_expr='\-'$MONTH
   else
     grep_expr=$MONTH
   fi

   for file in *eqllogmgr* ; do
     ftx "$file" | layoutcc
     grep "$grep_expr" "$file" |
        perl -ne 'print if /-2018/' |
        perl -pe 's/......-2018/\e[1;32m$&\e[0m/g' |
        sed '$d'
     echo
     ft1
   done 

   ;;
```

Note: I also added some quoting, removed the unnecessary colons, and got rid of the unnecessary `cat` command (just pass the filename directly to `grep` - no need for an extra pipe).

* Turns out what you were trying would actually work, although I personally don't think it's very concise. Example:

```
$ show=men
$ echo -e "Alice\nBob\nCarol\nDavid" | if [[ "$show" = "men" ]]; then egrep 'Bob|David'; else egrep 'Alice|Carol'; fi
Bob
David

$ show=women
$ echo -e "Alice\nBob\nCarol\nDavid" | if [[ "$show" = "men" ]]; then egrep 'Bob|David'; else egrep 'Alice|Carol'; fi
Alice
Carol
```

Comment: Setting the grep expression solved my issue and works as intended. Thanks for your help, i also learned some other things about my work through your removal of extra stuff.